# Trouble Making 3rd-Order Sympletic Integrator for Planitary N-Body Problem (A Hamiltonian System)

Tags: computational-physics, fortran, integration

I am doing a solar-system simulation. I am using Ruth's 3rd order sympletic integrator to avoid the problem of Energy Drift (which I had with RK4), but the  the planets quickly leave orbit, and energy is by no means conserved (just like with RK4).

[image: Here is Ruth's Integrator.]

I applied this to the N-body problem with the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(KE=1/2mv^2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have implemented this into Fortran 2008, where x, a, v, p, and m are all vectors of length 30, which hold the x,y,z position, x,y,z acceleration, x,y,z velocity, x,y,z momentum, and m,m,m respectively for 10 separate bodies in the solar system (Planets + Sun + Pluto).

Acceleration on each body is calculated as the sum of a=GM/(r^2) for x,y,z for each other body on each body.

Here is the integration part of the code:

```
!----------Looping Through Time-----------
do while(t<365.250000d0) ! Length of simulation in days
    !----------Calculating Values-----------
    call calc_acc(masses,x,a)
    p1=p+(7.0d0/24.0d0)*h*m*a
    x1=x+(2.0d0/3.0d0)*h*p1/m
    call calc_acc(masses,x1,a)
    p2=p1+(3.0d0/4.0d0)*h*m*a
    x2=x1-(2.0d0/3.0d0)*h*p2/m
    call calc_acc(masses,x2,a)
    p=p2-(1.0d0/24.0d0)*h*m*a
    x=x2+h*p/m
    v=p/m
    t=t+h
    !----------Saving Values-----------
    do bodnum=1,10,1
        write((100+bodnum),*) t, x((1+3*(bodnum-1)):(3+3*(bodnum-1))), v((1+3*(bodnum-1)):(3+3*(bodnum-1)))
        write((200+bodnum),*) x((1+3*(bodnum-1))), x((2+3*(bodnum-1))), x((3+3*(bodnum-1)))
    end do 
end do
```

The full program can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15vWpQzab3bYYxUiYwOpjui6wJQ8ArhC5/view?usp=sharing).

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to hyperlink this before, but [here](http://cds.cern.ch/record/143981/files/cer-000055082.pdf) is Ruth's paper. And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_drift) is a page on Energy Drift.

Comment: Welcome to scicomp! A tip: You can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to typeset your mathematical formulas. This will make the question much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you think the formula

```
to_add=(rj-ri)*big_g*masses(i)*masses(j)/((abs(rj-ri))**3.0d0)
```

does, especially the denominator? For the correct physics it should be the third power of the Euclidean distance.

Comment: I'd think that `abs` applied to a vector produces the vector of absolute values. Replacing with `sum((rj-ri)**2)**1.5` does also not change the general divergence.

Comment: I think that abs(vector) is [|x|,|y|,|z|], while norm2(vector) is Euclidian Distance of the vector

Comment: Yes, that works too. Check again the computation of `big_g`, using the formula in the comment I arrive at `2.670d-54`. Also check all the signs of the initial conditions, in the earth data there is a minus missing in the position coordinates.

Comment: Vielen Dank. The problem was twofold: 1) I should have used norm2 instead of abs. 2) My data was messed up, so I tried switching to some one else's, but I forgot to change the units when I did.